# MySQL SELECT WHERE LIKE anything but a number

Tags: mysql, select, sql-like

I'm having some problem with a SELECT query using the LIKE clause. I need to fetch all the records that have a category id in one certain field. All the category ids are stored like this:

1;2;4;11;12;22;32;

What is happening is that the following query

> SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `catids` LIKE '%2;%'

will select all the records that have the category id 2 but also the ones with the category 12, 22, 32 etc..Unfortunately the code for storing the category ids is not modificable and the number 2 is read from a variable.
I tried using a NOT LIKE clause next to it but i cannot repeat it 10 times in order to avoid 12, 22, 32, 42 etc...

Does anybody know a way to tell the clause LIKE to fetch anything with % that can be empty or ; but not a number? Because if the category id to fetch was 1 in the example above the string would start with the number 1 (so it wouldn't have a ; on the left) but it would fetch 11 as well.

Thank you

Comment: You can store data as ;1;2;4;11;12;22;32; add extra separator at starting  and change query to LIKE '%;2;%

Comment: Why is your database designed in such a way that it makes using it anything but possible?

Comment: You better reorganize your tables to get rid of storing values in one field.

Comment: It is not good idea to use this way to link tables. You should use separate table to join your mytable with category table

Comment: I don't know why in a case like that you dont use 2 primary keys, 1 as `id` and this one, `catids`. Then you can do a select like `WHERE catids IN (1,2,4,11...)` and if you want to restrict more, you have your first `id`. `WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4...) AND catids IN (1,2,4...)` etc. You have a lot of possibilities to work better with your database.

Comment: @FaishalSaiyed, N.B., Heavy i know that the database should be reorganized but unfortunately it is not possible! It is not my code. Thank you anyways

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper solution is to redesign your tables and normalize that field, so you store those IDs in a sub-table, one ID per record. Then your problem goes away.

Failing that, you'll need an ugly WHERE clause to handle all possible cases:

```
WHERE
      catids = 2             // the only ID in the field
   OR catids LIKE '2;%'      // ID is at the START of the id list
   OR catids LIKE '%;2;%'    // ID is somewhere in the MIDDLE of the list
   OR catids LIKE '%;2'      // ID is at the END of the list
```

If you had a properly normalized design, the clause would simply be

```
WHERE subtable.catids = 2
```

Comment: Thank you. This will work. I know that it's a really ugly WHERE clause but that's how the code is and cannot be changed!

Answer (score 0):

I second (and third) the idea that you need to redesign your tables. That said, you could also do something like this:

```
WHERE CONCAT(';', catids, ';') LIKE '%;2;%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using REGEXP... Something like...

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE catids REGEXP '(\d|;|^)2;'
```